# Creating Batch files for extracting

Tags: batch-file, extract, rar

Hello I am new to batch file,

I am trying to create a batch file which can extract specific image file from a .RAR file, and rename the extracted file same as the .RAR file.

FYI: The process needs to be done on multiple RAR files in same folder.

Any help will be appriciated :)
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps you:
you basically first set the rar and unrar location of e.g. WinRar:

set rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\RAR.exe

set unrar=%programFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe

and then you compress like this:

"%rar%" a "drop location" "target location"

or decompress like this:

%unrar% e "target location"

Source: http://batch.maxforum.org/2010/08/30/how-to-rar-unrar-via-batch/

Comment: Thanks Fourier, 

Actually I have multiple files in the RAR file and I want to extract only a single specific file from it, and rename the extracted file with the RAR file name itself.

Thanks